# Finding child element from iFrame via getElementById or other technique?

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

I have an iframe on my page, and need to get a child element from it whose ID I have.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').getElementById('child element ID')
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to accomplish this.  Unfortunately I don't have access to jQuery or other handy libraries on this page.

Comment: The killer question, of course, is: Is your iframe pointing to a page that's on the same domain (and HTTP protocol) as the base webpage?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to access the iframe document, here is a cross-browser way to do it:

```
var ifr=document.getElementById('iframeID');
var doc=ifr.contentWindow||ifr.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc=doc.document;
```

You can then reach the iframe content:

```
doc.getElementById('child element ID')
```

Note: this will only work within a same domain, due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).