# How to find specific element inside nested iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to find a specific element, which is inside an iframe, from a parent component, the structure would be something like this: (Just an example)
<sub>***Edit:*** See comments below concerning the nature of this example</sub>

```
<iframe id ='if1'>
    <iframe id ='if2'>
        <iframe id ='if3'>
            <iframe id ='if4'>
                <input type='hidden' id ='elementToBeFound'>
            </iframe>
        </iframe>
    </iframe>
</iframe>
```

Now, how can i do this with javascript? (Can also be jquery or another helper)
I have a reference to the first iframe ('if1'), i wanted to search all child nodes until i found 'elementToBeFound'.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

My question is different from the existing ones, because i want to access multiple iframes inside iframes, not only one level.

Comment: Do you want to find it with id? why dont you use getElementById?

Comment: That's not going to work, anything that is in between an iframe's tags would never be rendered with modern browsers. Also, none of these iframes have a `src` or `srcdoc` attribute which makes it broken even further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding child element from iFrame via getElementById or other technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699105/finding-child-element-from-iframe-via-getelementbyid-or-other-technique)

Comment: @zer00ne is right, no iframe is rendered inside other iframe.  
I just found this structure in production (it must have been generated dynamically, with src) and wanted to find an element.      
Anyways, i could solve the problem without having to access it, so the problem was dodged.

Comment: Hi @EliâMelfior glad you resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive that something like this should work:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('if1').contentDocument
.getElementById('if2').contentDocument
.getElementById('if3').contentDocument
.getElementById('if4').contentDocument
.getElementById('elementToBeFound')
```

But for sure all windows should be loaded to do that. In real workld it may be more complicated you will need to listen for load event for each iframe to be able to check what is inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to query for any element on the page, regardless of if it is nested inside of an iframe:

```
function querySelectorAllInIframes(selector) {
  let elements = [];

  const recurse = (contentWindow = window) => {

    const iframes = contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll('iframe');
    iframes.forEach(iframe => recurse(iframe.contentWindow));
    
    elements = elements.concat(contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll(selector));
  }

  recurse();

  return elements;
};

querySelectorAllInIframes('#elementToBeFound');
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that each of the iframes on the page will need to be of the same-origin, or this function will throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the div element by using `iframe.contentWindow` call.

Here is the example:

> **NOTE : You have to use "src" (external iframes) to make it work**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>IF1</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <iframe id='if1' src="./iframe2.html">
        <!-- <iframe id='if2'>
          <iframe id='if3'>
            <iframe id='if4'> -->
              <!-- <div id='elementToFind'>Hello</div> -->
            <!-- </iframe>
          </iframe>
        </iframe> -->
      </iframe>

      <script>

        window.onload = function() {
          let if1 = document.getElementById('if1').contentWindow;
          let if2 = if1.document.getElementById('if2').contentWindow;
          let div = if2.document.getElementById('elementToFind');
          console.log(div)
        }

      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```